# Convert HTML to plain text keeping links, bold and italic in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am configuring an API to send an email using the content of a publication as the body of the email. The text editor used for the publication save the text in HTML so I needed to convert the result into plain text. There are other questions that have gave me a solution, but I would like to keep from the original text the bold text, italic and the links. So this is what I have:

- Body of a test publicacion:

**This is bold text.**

This is regular text.

*This is italic.*

This is a link.

Then in the script I have the following function:

```
function htmlToText(html){
    //remove code brakes and tabs
    html = html.replace(/\n/g, "");
    html = html.replace(/\t/g, "");

    //keep html brakes and tabs
    html = html.replace(/<\/td>/g, "\t");
    html = html.replace(/<\/table>/g, "\n");
    html = html.replace(/<\/tr>/g, "\n");
    html = html.replace(/<\/p>/g, "\n");
    html = html.replace(/<\/div>/g, "\n");
    html = html.replace(/<\/h>/g, "\n");
    html = html.replace(/<br>/g, "\n"); html = html.replace(/<br( )*\/>/g, "\n");
    html = html.replace(/<a.*href="(.*?)".*>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, " $2 (Link->$1) ");

    //parse html into text
    var dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString('<!doctype html><body>' + html, 'text/html');
    return dom.body.textContent;
}
```

That gives me some plain text with nice line breaks, but I was wondering if I could get the bold, italic and links.

Thanks.

Comment: You've to style the link with CSS, plain text doesn't have any styles in it.

Comment: That's why it's called **plain** text in the first place ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some time on my hands and played around. This is what I came up with:

```js
const copy=document.createElement("div");
copy.innerHTML=container.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g," ").replace(/[\t\n]+/g,"");
const tags={B:["**","**",1],  // [<prefix>, <postfix>, <sequence-number> ]
            I:["*","*",2],
            H2:["##","\n",3],
            P:["\n","\n",4],
            DIV:["","\n",5],
            TD:["","\t",6]};
[...copy.querySelectorAll(Object.keys(tags).join(","))]
 .sort((a,b)=>tags[a.tagName][2]-tags[b.tagName][2])
 .forEach(e=>{
 const [a,b]=tags[e.tagName];
 e.innerHTML=(e.matches("TD:first-child") ? "\n": a) + e.innerHTML + b;
});
console.log(copy.textContent.replace(/^ */mg,""));
```

```html
<div id="container">
<H2>Second level heading</H2>
<div><div>
A <b>first div</b> with a 
<a href="abc.html">link (abc)</a> and a
<p>paragraph having itself another <a href="def.html">link (def)</a> in it.</p>
</div>
</div>
And here is some more <i>"lost" text</i> ...
<table>
<tr><td>one</td><td><b>two</b></td><td>three</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>d</td><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Instead of using regexp to "parse" the html I chose to actually treat it in a DOM way: I create a new div element (`copy`) into which I insert the original `.innerHTML`. For particular element types I then define some pre- and postfixes that should surround the original `.innerHTML`. These are stored in `tags` and applied on the freshly created div element.

This is done by selecting all of the "special" elements (as specified by the  `tags`-keys)  and processing them in a given sequential order. Afterwards I simply return the `.textContent` of the modified `copy` element.

Plain text cannot really render bold or italics text decoration. For this reason I used modifiers in the markdown style (*:italics, **:bold)